# light streamer nodejs hello world example throwing error

Tags: node.js, lightstreamer

hello every one i am new in nodejs and want to use the light streamer  for my site there is a example on git when i tried to deployed it on my local instance throwing the below error any idea will be appreciated thanks in advance...

here is the example i want to deploy

[Light streamer nodejs example](https://github.com/Weswit/Lightstreamer-example-HelloWorld-adapter-node)

E:\wamp\www\nodeJs\lightstream>node helloworld.js

events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)

Answer (score 2):

ECONNREFUSED suggests that the application is not able to connect to the desired TCP port (most likely it is being blocked by a firewall or there is no application listening on that port).

Assuming you have not changed the configuration in helloworld.js:

Have you installed the lightstream server locally and checked it is running? If so, check Windows Firewall and add rules to allow inbound ports 6663 and 6664.

Comment: thanks for reply @joGoFo yes i have installed lightstream server and it is working fine with its builtin demos but when i tried to use it with a nodejs adapter it fails have you ever tried this if yes kindly guide me..thanks again

Comment: did you try @JoGoFo suggestions? 
did you deploy a new adapters.xml in your Lightstreamer server adapters folder?

Comment: what about adapters.xml ?